# Jenkins groovy error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{returnStatus=true} ...]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to run below code in Jenkins DSL pipeline but getting an error, what could be the issue

```
Closure test = { dockerImageName ->
    sh('''cd ''' + dir + ''' \
        && if make image ''' + dockerImageName + ''' 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then exit 1; fi''',
        returnStatus: true
    )
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{returnStatus=true}, cd dir && if make image docker-xxx.com/dir 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then exit 1; fi]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to give the argument name for the first argument, try as following:

```
Closure test = { dockerImageName ->
    sh(script: '''cd ''' + dir + ''' \
        && if make image ''' + dockerImageName + ''' 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then exit 1; fi''',
        returnStatus: true
    )
}
```